# mapped type that ensures a string union has an element of a specific string literal

Tags: typescript

I want to create a Mapped type that states that a `field` called `status` allows a union of strings and one of the elements of the union must be `ready`:

This works

```
export type ValidServiceState = HasReady<{ status: "ready" }>;
```

but so this should be good but is currently mapping to never because it has extra values in the union.

```
// this should be good because ready is one of the allowable values
export type ValidServiceState = HasReady<{ status: "ready" | "bananas" }>;
```

but this should and does map to `never`

```
// should be never
export type InvalidServiceState = HasReady<{ status: "not_ready"  |  "something_else_that_is_not_ready" }>;
```

I have tried this

```
type HasReady<S extends { status: string } > = S extends { status: "ready" }
  ? S
  : never;
```

But this only allows a strict `{ status: "ready}`

Here is a complete version

```
type HasReady<S extends { status: string }> = S extends { status: "ready" }
  ? S
  : never;

// this should be good because ready is one of the allowable values
export type ValidServiceState = HasReady<{ status: "ready" | "bananas" }>;

// never
export type InvalidServiceState = HasReady<{ status: "not_ready" }>;
```

Here is a [playground with the above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwEoTgExAHgMpQgD2AgDs0EoBvKBYOYAVwQC5rgAnAS2IHMoBfAHxQAvFFwEipclRp1GLAERtUGBfwBQUKAH4xmqC2IQAbhDYBudVYD01qMAAWHcggcB7egBs0UAEbRuNzcffwBjOEZoZXQQKGcoNyMEgDN7B2g4T083AHc4X09oY0z6CAR1AjA3NmB7cGgANUyONGwzYw5QiGxaIhFYRBQYzBle+SglFRA1AB8J3zhiRcQ1QUt1WygjUzYK-CqausgoAEliYs8WtrYOrp66aFF4ZCmR1jlmCeI3YAB9aNU-AE5iAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap sides on `extends` in type definition:

```
type HasReady<S extends { status: string }> = { status: "ready" } extends S 
  ? S
  : never;
```

Explanation:

`{ status: "ready" | "bananas" } extends { status: "ready" } ? { status: "ready" | "bananas" } : never`

-->

`({ status: "ready" } extends { status: "ready" } ? { status: "ready" | "bananas" } : never) & ({ status: "bananas" } extends { status: "ready" } ? { status: "ready" | "bananas" } : never)`

-->

`{ status: "ready" | "bananas" } & never`

-->

`never`